# The trigger setting for the Lambda arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:xxxxxxxxx:function:nodejs-alexa-skill is invalid. Error code: SkillManifestError

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I am not able to setup the lambda function for my alexa skill. I keep getting the following error:

```
The trigger setting for the Lambda arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:xxxxx:function:nodejs-alexa-skill is invalid. Error code: SkillManifestError
```

But I do have other skills which are using the lambda function without any errors. All the other settings seem to be fine. Could you please let me know what the error is ?

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

Most probably you forgot to add "Alexa Skills Kit" as a trigger for your lambda function. You need to add a new trigger for every skill which you want to use with your lambda.
Go into the aws lambda console

-> choose your lambda

-> "Configuration"

-> "Add trigger"

[image]

Comment: Can you show how one would "add the Alexa Skills Kit as a trigger for your lambda function."

Comment: @AlexMarks ok, I added a picture

Answer (score 1):

Basically, I had copied wrong skill id to Alexa Skills Kit trigger in the lambda function.

Thanks